# How to fix TrustedHTML assignment error with Dotnet web form [innerHTML]

Tags: html, asp.net, content-security-policy

i used a header which is for Content Secure Policy and that is giving error that Failed to set inner html in chrome only...is there any fix for that?

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://userservices.vip.symantec.com  https://www.gstatic.com https://translate.google.com https://translate.googleapis.com https://translate-pa.googleapis.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes'; object-src 'none';  img-src 'self' data: https: http://translate.google.com; child-src https://dxc.mediaplatform.com; require-trusted-types-for 'script'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is likely to change from innerHTML to innerText if your output doesn't require any markup.

Otherwise it is likely this part of your CSP that is causing trouble: "require-trusted-types-for 'script';" You can look into trusted types and try to configure it correctly, but this could be a bit complex.

Comment: actually converting all innerhtml to innertext on whole portal will be big chnage , all the pages need to check and update...